# Confirm box doesnt work when i get a value from a form php and javascript

Tags: php, javascript

This seems really odd to me, but my popup confirm box will work when i just call the function, but as soon as i try to get a value from a form in my php code, the popup box doesnt work at all!

javascipt:

```
function ConfirmBox(){
    cert = cValForm.elements["cVal"].value;
    answer = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete " + cert + " and all of its courses?");
     if (answer){
         alert("Entry Deleted");
     }
     else{
         alert("No action taken");
     }             
}
```

PHP:

```
echo "<form name='cValForm'>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='cVal' value='TEST' /> ";
echo "<input type='button' onclick='ConfirmBox()' value='Delete'/>";
echo "</form>";
```

As soon as i comment out the line:

```
cert = cValForm.elements["cVal"].value;
```

As well as getting rid of the cert value in the string, the popup works completely fine.  Am i getting the value from the form wrong? Or am i completely missing something here? Thanks!

Comment: Where/how is `cValForm` defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you script breaks, because it is not able to find the value of the `cVal` field.

Change your HTML to use Ids as well as names:

```
<form name='cValForm'>
  <input type='hidden' id="cVal" name='cVal' value='TEST' />
  <input type='button' onclick='ConfirmBox()' value='Delete'/>
</form>
```

And then check in JavaScript first, if the element was selected at all:

```
function ConfirmBox(){
    var certField = document.getElementById( 'cVal' );
    var cert = certField ? certField.value : '';
    var answer = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete " + cert + " and all of its courses?");
     if (answer){
         alert("Entry Deleted");
     }
     else{
         alert("No action taken");
     }             
}
```

Besides, you should add the keyword `var` to all you variable declarations to limit the scope of these vars to the local function. In your case those variables would have been global, which may have some side-effects.

Comment: Thanks! That worked perfectly for me, and thanks for the tip on 'var'!

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
function ConfirmBox(){
    cValForm = document.forms[index];
    cert = cValForm.elements["cVal"].value;
    answer = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete " + cert + " and all of its courses?");
     if (answer){
         alert("Entry Deleted");
     }
     else{
         alert("No action taken");
     }             
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
var cert = document.getElementsByName("cVal").value
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript Line 2 changes to:

```
cert = document.getElementById('cVal');
```

PHP Line 2 changes to:

```
echo "<input type='hidden' id='cVal' value='TEST' /> ";
```